# ScrollMagic and anchor smooth scrolling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, scrollmagic

i'm having a real hard time implementing ScrollMagic Section Wipes and smooth scroll to anchors. The thing is i can use the links to scroll down but not up! I can imagine this happens because the underlying sections are stuck at top and there is really nothing to scroll to.

I have an example of what i mean in: http://www.globovac.net/scroll

In this example, if i click "UNITS" i get a blue section, that's perfect. I need to click "HOME" and the blue section goes down and shows the first green one again.

Can someone help me, i would really like to implement ScrollMagic but it's useless without a proper menu. Thank you all in advance!

EDIT:

What i basically would like to do is a combination of this anchor navigation:

codepen.io/grayghostvisuals/pen/EtdwL

with this Section Wipes example:
http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/section_wipes_natural.html

How hard can this be?...

Comment: You might want to consider using [fullPage.js parallax](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/parallax.html). Easy to link with a menu and configurable offset.

Comment: Looks really interesting and simple, i'll definitely take a closer look. Thank you!